# PHP-FPM unable to find or access status shared memory

Tags: php, php-fpm

I am running a busy magento 2 load balanced web server with 3 back-end PHP-FPM servers and a shared EFS network filesystem on AWS cloud. There are lots of concurrent users and everything works fine except the fact that randomly, from time to time I see the following errors in the error log:

```
May 4 15:27:01 app-node php_fpm_error [04-May-2023 15:27:01] WARNING: [pool pool.name] child 135046 said into stderr: ERROR: scoreboard: failed to lock (already locked)
May 4 15:27:01 app-node php_fpm_error [04-May-2023 15:27:01] WARNING: [pool pool.name] child 135046 said into stderr: ERROR: status: unable to find or access status shared memory
```

The PHP version used is 8.1.18 on Ubuntu 22 LTS. The PHP-FPM pool config is below:

```
[pool.name]
pm.status_path = /status
;listen = 127.0.0.1:5001
listen = /run/php-fpm/pool.sock
listen.owner = wwwuser
listen.group = wwwgroup
listen.mode = 0660
user = wwwuser
group = wwwgroup
listen.backlog = 1024
pm = static
pm.max_children = 12
pm.max_requests = 1000
request_terminate_timeout = 0
rlimit_files = 4096
catch_workers_output = yes
security.limit_extensions = .php .phar
```

I searched on google and I found absolutely nothing about these 2 errors.

Please help.
THanks

Comment: Do you have defined on your machine shared memory? `ipcs -lm`

Comment: I have this:```root@app-node-172-23-0-107:~# ipcs -lm

------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 18014398509465599
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 18446744073709551612
min seg size (bytes) = 1```

Comment: is it hitting the limits?

Comment: IMHO no, you have good amount of shared memory. Probably the problem is on other place.